# master detail flow version support

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am currently developing an app using android API version 14 using master detail flow activity.

- specification: minsdkversion:11
- targetsdkversion:14

Now I want to develop the same app using android API version 16. So, I created a new project.

- specification: minsdkversion:11
- targetsdkversion:16

... and copied the used file here. It is running fine on emulator. But when I installed it on a smart phone (android 4.1.2), it crashes.

I have debugged the app and it says that android.jar does not have source. Does this mean that android 4.1.2 does not support master detail flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have debugged the app and it says that android.jar does not have source.

You are getting this message because you are trying to step into Android source code in Eclipse.

> Is this mean that android 4.1.2 does not support master detaail flow?

Every computer with a monitor supports "master detaail flow". The master-detail flow is a UI pattern, one that has been used for decades.

All versions of Android support master-detail flow, including Android 4.1.2. If you wish to use fragments for the master-detail implementation, the Android Support package's backport of fragments works back to Android 1.6.

> But when i installed it on a smart phone(android 4.1.2),is crashes.

Look at LogCat and examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I managed to acquire a samsung galaxy grand(4.1.2) and did the debugging. i dont have the stack trace. but it gave an null pointer exception for a table layout. but that same layout is working fine in emulator and in tabs. so i really dont understand the exact problem..